# How can I call a method that returns an object from a client windows phone 8.0 silverlight using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have implemented a library WCF service , and I have tested it in the WCF test client and it works perfectly, but when I've tried to call the methods from the hosting application (windows phone 8.0 silverlight), All the methods were(void), they works but they return nothing !

In contrary to Windows Phone, I succeeded to host the same wcf library service in Winforms where the methods can return objects.
I am a beginner in WCF, and I have tried several solutions without success !

I have 3 classes : DAO.cs , Article.cs , Client.cs

And a WCF service : IMetier.cs and Metier.cs

And Entity Framework Model

The Client class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    public string NoClient { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TypeClient { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Ville { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ccp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RegionClient { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<bool> Depositaire { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<bool> CentreRegional { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CodeMagazin { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<bool> ClientComptant { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the interface: IMetier.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMetier
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void addClient(Client client);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Client> GetClients();
    }
}
```

Here is the class Metier.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Metier : IMetier
    {
        DAO dao = new DAO();

        void addClient(Client client)
        {
            dao.addClient(client);
        }

        public List<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return dao.GetClients();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, 
WCF uses asynchronous methods using threads, I should use these methods synchronously.
The second way is to implement the event GetClienteEventArgs and retrieve my results from the event properties.
In the client application constructor we have to handle the event

```
        ServiceMetier.MetierClient metier = new ServiceMetier.MetierClient();
        metier.GetClientsAsync();
        metier.GetClientsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceMetier.ListerClientsCompletedEventArgs>(ListerClients_Completed);
```

then implement it

```
    void GetClients_Completed(object sender, ListerClientsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ServiceMetier.Client> clients =e.Result;
    }
```

Note that e.Result is the returning statement of the service method